# Kafka source - sink connectors - multiple tables with single topic

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Populating messages from different tables to a single topic.  But need to separate out messages and sink to destination table set with same names.

Using debezium/connect, I am populating the topic from source table with jdbc source connector. With jdbc sink connector, I populate the destination table. (from topic to destination table) In thi scenario, I need 1 topic for 1 table. Since there are 100's of tables, I need to have a single topic to sync many tables

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to do, it is very general and not clear. Add more information about what you tried or what are you aiming for.

Comment: Debezium does not use JDBC as a source....

Comment: @cricket_007 I do it with debezium/connect container.

Comment: Sure. The question said JDBC, though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Kafka Connect transforms to modify the topic / table names in flight.

It seems you may want to use a `RegexRouter` to collect multiple topics together.

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html